# iPhone Settings Bundle - Read-only setting

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, settings.bundle

Is it possible to have a read-only setting (from the user's perspective, but read/write from my app) in the settings bundle.  I'm looking to display something like:

Registered: YES/NO

But I don't want to show a switch because I don't want the user to be able to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title type displays a read-only string value. You can use this type to display read-only preference values. (If the preference contains cryptic or nonintuitive values, this type lets you map the possible values to custom strings.)
The key for this type is [PSTitleValueSpecifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html).

Comment: This solution is the closest to my needs.  I will use a string.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No.

For the app to have read write ideally it needs to be in the Settings.bundle which goes into the Documents folder. You could just disable user interaction on the switch?

Comment: I have to second this one. Just create a bundle (plist?) in the application, let the view read this on load, then set all the values on the switches/textboxes/stuff according to the info you've read from that file.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4+ set the type to title of the textfield.